# TeamCity - Can I cancel currently running builds of the same configuration when starting a new build?

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, integration-testing

I have some long running integration tests that are automatically run by the TeamCity server when I commit to source control.

TeamCity allows me to prevent these tasks from taking up all the build agents concurrently by limiting the simultaneous builds, however I wonder if it's possible to have TeamCity cancel any currently running tasks of this configuration when a new one starts?

In this environment as soon as there is a new commit to source control, old runs of the integration tests are irrelevant, so I don't want the server to waste its time running tests for old versions.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible, and I would say this is by design.

Imagine a world where this is allowed, you would never know which commit caused a test to start failing. If you had enough overlapping commits you could have 50 builds before you know that the final test to be run fails, and would have no idea whether it was the last commit or the one 49 before that which caused it to fail.

IMHO you would be better focusing efforts into making so that multiple runs can happen simultaneously on different servers, to get the speed up you want, not throwing the baby out with the bath water

**UPDATE**

Whilst I don't think this is supported out of the box, if I had to do this I think I would look at [getting a notification when a build starts](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Subscribing+to+Notifications) (seems there are no notifications for builds being queued, so you'll have to allow multiple builds to run concurrently for this to work) and then you [can use the API to do cancel the other builds:](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/REST+API#RESTAPI-BuildCanceling%2FStopping).

you can get a [list of builds](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/REST+API#RESTAPI-BuildRequests) using the API as well so should be able to cancel all the ones which are not the most recent

Comment: First of all thanks for your comment. However tests in question are integration tests that can be broken by environmental issues outside of the codebase (think database changes), hence that sort of tracking is potentially useless. I understand the design concerns of the TeamCity team and that this is an edge case but for this purpose being able to cancel a build would actually be useful. I agree that if I were able to cut down the time the tests take to be within a reasonable time frame, the problem would be irrelevant, however I'm not sure that's possible here and certainly not sustainable.

Comment: @LiamFlanagan I understand that everyone has edge cases, and sometimes pragmatism wins, regardless of the ugliness. At the end of the day teamcity is a webapp, and the cancellation happens because someone calls a method on TC. You could certainly fake this. I'll update my answer with what I would look at

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible. You can cancel it manually. Or you can add a quiet period (default is 60 seconds) so a build doesn't start immediately when something has been pushed. Then if some commits arrive after few seconds or minutes, they will be included in the TeamCity build.

Comment: I presume @gerald was referring to either: 
- Cancelling it from the running build agent:
  - Agents (at the top of the dashboard)
    - Find the relevant running build
     - Pressing the stop button on the right hand side
or removing it from the build queue:
- Build Queue (at the top of the dashboard):
   - Find the relevant build in the queue
     - Pressing the remove button on the right hand side

(edited because I pressed enter too quickly!)

Answer (score 1):

My solution is similar to [Sam's update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28191996/6051919) but I would use a "preamble" configuration that is triggered by commits to source control. This job is solely responsible for checking to see if any of your integration test jobs are already running and [stopping them with a REST API call](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/REST+API#RESTAPI-BuildCanceling%2FStopping), as needed.

The main integrations tests are run from a dedicated job configuration that uses a build finish trigger associated with the preamble configuration.

This setup makes it quite straightforward to query which jobs are running and may need to be cancelled if there is newer work to do. So the steps become:

1. Preamble - cancel any running integration test job, triggered by VCS
2. Integration test - triggered by completion of a "Preamble" build

Comment: What do you mean with "preamble" configuration? Do you mean a first build step or is this some feature I can't seem to find information about?

Comment: Anyway, [this powershell](https://ict.ken.be/stop-teamcity-build-when-other-build-starts) works for me. Thanks for pointing me in the correct direction.